# Set title when share images and videos in flutter

Tags: flutter, share

For sharing images and videos now using `easy_flutter_share` package, but when I use `Share.files(..)` I can't change title of activity view. When I select one image and one video, title automaticly change ***1 image and 1 document***, but I want write another title. How can I fix it in IOS?

Comment: Try this package: https://pub.dev/packages/share#-readme-tab-

Comment: this package using for sharing **only text**